# Harry Potter fanfic that narrates the movies making fun of it, and mainly Steve Kloves

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

I remember reading a harry potter fanfic series somewhere in 2010-2012(roughly) that narrates through the movies, and basically makes fun of it. It was posted on fanfiction.net though I'm not able to find it on searching for it there recently.

There were multiple fics done, each based on a movie up until the 4th or 5th movie iirc. The author makes fun of multiple movie decisions like mary-sueing Hermione, making Ron a bufoon etc. It also makes fun of Steve Kloves multiple times.

The format was like a script book so it would be like:

> (scene description in brackets)
>
> Harry: blah blah blah
>
> Hermione: reply blah blah
>
> (funny comment by author/narrator in brackets)

I remember in the fic based on third movie where the actor who played Dumbledore changes, there was a funny reaction when new-Dumbledore appears and everybody is confused about who this guy is.

Comment: ALMOST sounds like RiffTrax.

Comment: Hi, can you provide a link for that?

Comment: Just add a .com [RiffTrax](https://www.rifftrax.com/). I forget who did it, but there's also a great commentary called "Wizard People Dear Reader." Both commentaries are very funny.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but in my case, it's by a small author who wrote on fanfiction.net, and it was text only.

Comment: FanFiction.net don't actually allow fanfics in script format like that, and so they may have removed it from the website, which might be why you can't find it. That might make it almost impossible to track down, I'm afraid. Also, who is Steve Kloves?

Comment: @F1Krazy the guy who wrote the screenplays, apparently ([IMDb profile](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0460141/))

Comment: @F1Krazy oh damn. I loved that thing. Hopefully, there may be some way to recover it using the Wayback machine. Lemme check. And Steve Kloves is the writer of the screnplay as Jenayah said

Comment: Something like '[My Goblet of Fire Parody](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/4232226/1/My-Goblet-of-Fire-Parody)?

Comment: @Valorum Thank you! it's either that one or the answer posted by Laurel.

Comment: Actually just confirmed, It seems like its the one posted by Laurel. Buth thanks for this one as well!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it [Year Three at Warner Brothers](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/4597273/1/Year-Three-at-Warner-Brothers)
by obsessmuch?

> *The STUDENTS settle down to eat while being serenaded by a cute little CHOIR with toad accompaniment. They are conducted by the newly made­over PROFESSOR F
>   and when they are finished they move aside to reveal… similarly newly made over DUMBLEDORE!*
>
> DUMBLEDORE: Greetings, students!
>   STUDENT #1: Who the hell are you?
>   STUDENT #2: He must have broken into the castle!
>   STUDENT #3: He must have killed Dumbledore, usurped his power and seized his crown!
>   ALL STUDENTS: *(panic)*
>   DUMBLEDORE: It's okay, my dears. I'm the new Dumbledore. And honestly, you won't even notice the difference. Until movie 4, that is. But until then, my psychopathic tendencies are going to remain firmly under wraps.

The author has two other fics, one for year four, one for year five.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much!!

Comment: @ColonD since you're still around, it would be nice of you to accept Laurel's answer, as you've confirmed it is the right one :)

Comment: Oops sorry, I forgot! Done,